# Passing data to controller on row bases

Tags: php, html, laravel-4.2

I have a table display and each row contains a button. With this button l have to pass the id to the controller where using this Admin can view user details one by one.

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="text-align: center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Applicant ID</th>
            <th>Full name</th>
            <th>Position applied</th>
            <th>Date & time applied</th>
            <th>View CV</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($jobapplied as $row)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$row->app_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->position}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->created_at}}</td>
            <td>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
             default" name="viewcv"> View</button> <br>
            <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And whats your problem...?

Comment: Do you want that the user goes to a "show" view or something like this?

Comment: Dont know how to pass the id for each user

Comment: If you want to redirect then use Anchor tag instead of Submit button,In this way you will be easily appending the ID in your link .

Comment: Can you suggest any sample ?

Comment: have added my answer plz check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code , hope it helps:

```
 <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="text-align: center">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Applicant ID</th>
                                    <th>Full name</th>
                                    <th>Position applied</th>
                                    <th>Date & time applied</th>
                                    <th>View CV</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($jobapplied as $row)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$row->app_id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$row->fullname}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$row->position}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$row->created_at}}</td>
                                    <td><a href="path/to/your/controller/{{$row->id}}">CV</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Assuming you want to pass the field "id" or change it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link to a `show` view, try something like this:

```
@foreach ($jobapplied as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$row->app_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->fullname}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->position}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->created_at}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{action('JobController@show', $row->id)}}" class="btn btn-default">View</button>                                 
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This will create a link to a view, where you can show the data.

In your controller `JobController`, you must create a function that receives the data:

```
public function show(Request $request, $id) {
...
}
```

Comment: I created this methods but dont know how to run on submit of view button.
public function viewontable(Request $request, $id) {

        $user = Apply::where('user_id', $id)->first();
        if (!$user) {
            return View::make('createcv', array('message' => 'You must create your CV first to be able to view it.!'));
        } else {
            $data = Apply::where('user_id', $id)->get();

Comment: $applicant_id = Apply::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('id');
            $language = Language::where('app_id', $applicant_id)->get();
            $skills = Skills::where('app_id', $applicant_id)->get();
            return View::make('pdf_report/html_resume', compact('data', 'language', 'skills'));
        }
    }

Comment: If you just want to redirect the user to a show view, you don't need to create a button and submit a form. Only an anchor is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the id of the record to controller function and get the details from database.

```
<td>
   <a href="{{URL::route('routeName',$row->app_id)}}" class="btn btn-default" name="viewcv"> View</a> <br>         
</td>
```